# ¿Hay modo de distinguir el borrado manual de un objeto?

Tags: python

Se entiende que distinguirlo del borrado que hace el recolector de basura. Me gustaría que el borrado explícito:

```
del objeto
```

Ejecutara algo que no se ejecuta cuando el objeto desaparece porque el recolector de basura detecta que ya no es necesario.

Sé que puedo hacer algo como:

```
objeto.delete()
```

para ejecutar el código adicional que deseo, pero no me parece del todo elegante, porque el objeto sigue existiendo.

Mi necesidad surge de que estoy escribiendo un pequeño *orm* y el objeto está asociado a su registro correspondiente en la base de datos. Me gustaría que borrar el objeto explícitamente significara borrar el registro, mientras que dejar que *muera* el objeto, no tuviera ningún efecto sobre la base de datos.

Comment: Hola, ¿a qué te refieres con "dejar que muera"?, entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es usar `del objeto` y que se borre el registro de la base de datos pero no entendí muy bien a lo que te refieres con dejar morir

Comment: Por *dejar morir* me refiero a que sea el recolector de basura el que se encargue de borrar el objeto. En ese caso, no quiero que se borre el registro. En caso contrario cada vez que leyera un registro de la base de datos (que se convierte, obviamente, en un objeto), acabaría por borrarse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que no entiendes bien cómo funciona el borrado de objetos. Con `del objeto` lo que haces es borrar una de las referencias al objeto, pero podrían haber más. Lo más común, por ejemplo, es que lo tengas referenciado desde atributos de otros objetos. Una regla a tener en cuenta es que el objeto siempre estará vivo mientras haya una referencia viva hacia él. Y sólo cuando la última referencia haya desaparecido, el objeto se borrará de memoria.

Previamente al borrado de memoria, se ejecuta el método `__del__`. No creo que sea el mejor sitio para borrar registros de una base de datos.

Te poco un ejemplo ilustrativo:

```
class C:
  def __del__(self):
    print("Borrado del objeto")

a = C()
b = a

print("Intento de borrado 1")
del a

print("Intento de borrado 2")
del b
```

Si lo pruebas, verás que el método `__del__` no es invocado hasta que haya desaparecido la referencia `b`.

Dicho lo cuál, advertir que es imposible forzar el borrado de todas las referencias de un objeto a no ser que las hubieras creado como *referencias débiles* (*weakrefs*).

Pero no veo modo de que te evites crear un método específico en el ORM para borrar registros.

Si quieres profundizar más, hace un tiempo escribí un artículo sobre [la vida de los objetos](http://blog.ch3m4.org/2013/11/09/python-eficiente-sobre-la-vida-de-los-objetos/).

Comment: Eso me sospechaba, pero he preguntado por si a alguien se le ocurría un método más elegante que el que he acabado implementando. Gracias por el enlace al artículo: lo leeré con detenimiento esta tarde: sopongo que seguirás diciendo las mismas cosas interesantes que en la lista de python. Un saludo.

Comment: Espero seguir contando cosas interesantes en ambos lados.

Comment: En cuanto al diseño del ORM, deberías tener en cuenta que puedes estar trabajando con un sistema transaccional. Por ejemplo, el borrado de un registro podría suponer un borrado en cadena o dejar incongruencias en las relaciones entre tablas. Más que tener acciones "atómicas" como `.delete()` deberías pensar en transacciones del estilo `.exec()` donde encadenes la ejecución de varias operaciones y tengas la opción de recuperar un estado anterior estable en caso de fallo.